# MCMC "best fit" determination for highly correlated/covariant parameters

Tags: estimation, optimization, markov-chain-montecarlo, fitting

People often get the "best fit" by finding the median of each dimension.  When posteriors are highly non-gaussian, and weirdly covariant, this can fail horribly.  For example, here's a schematic showing a posterior that is a perfect ring (with equal probability everywhere).  If you the median of both parameters you get a "solution" with zero support from the posterior.  The "true" solution should really be anywhere on the ring.  In practice, if you have a bunch of samples of the posterior (from an MCMC for example), how does one define or select a more appropriate "solution"?

[image]

Comment: One argument for using Bayesian analysis and posterior distributions is that this bypasses the need for a necessarily imperfect and sometimes absurd point estimate as in the above graph.